# Chrome and Microsoft Office 365 and Dropbox

Tags: google-chrome, office365

I no longer have an Office 365 account, but when I click on a document in Dropbox in Chrome it tries to open in Office 365. What settings do I need to change to have it open in regular Office?

Answer (score 0):

This more to do with File Associations within Windows rather than Chrome.

Within Windows Control Panel, go to Default Programs.  From here you can choose your default applications by File Type.

Comment: Does that work for files you're opening from inside Dropbox in the Web Browser? He's not opening them from the Dropbox folder on his computer, and online most of the info is about the Word/Browser integration that Dropbox supports.